# Remove crashed SCCM 2012 from Active Directory 2008 R2 (schema version 69)

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, sccm

Our VM SCCM 2012 as been deleted by other administrator the last years and we haven't backup.
I want remove all trace of SCCM from our Active directory and workstation but i don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reference to SCCM in Active Directory is the "System Management" container, which only exists [if you had created it in the first place](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb632591.aspx); if SCCM is no longer in use, you can safely delete it.

Unfortunately, there is no centralized way to uninstall the SCCM agent from all computers in your environment; you'll need to either perform a manual uninstallation or use some scripting (a startup script assigned via Group Policy could be a good solution). You'll find the relevant documentation [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb694276.aspx).